# How to import specific csv values as array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a mysql table that has postcode and co-ordinates that I would like to import to Mongo.  After exporting to csv and importing to MongoDB it looks like this

```
> db.postcode.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5596d56365f8d76adbae63ed"),
        "postcode" : "AB101XG",
        "latitude" : 57.14416516,
        "longitude" : -2.114847768
}
```

However, I would like to have the co-ordinates in a array format (assuming it is the format required for geo queries) as below

```
> db.postcode.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5596d56365f8d76adbae63ed"),
        "postcode" : "AB101XG",
        "loc" : [57.14416516, -2.114847768]
}
```

Being newbie to Mongo, I am not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: Can't you post process it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like post processing was the only way to go.

```
> db.postcode.find().forEach( function(r) { 
    r.loc = [r.latitude, r.longitude]; 
    db.postcode.save(r); 
  });
```

Comment: Just to clarify, `db.postcode.save(r)` does an update of the document as desired.